# What is the difference between `before_create` and `after_create` and when to use which?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I know that before_create is called before the object gets commuted to the database and after_create gets called after.

The only time when before_create will get called and after_create while not is if the object fails to meet data base constants (unique key, etc.). Other that that I can place all the logic from after_create in before_create

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please elaborate `Other that that I can place all the logic from after_create in before_create` for us to answer appropriately.

Answer (score 28):

In order to understand these two callbacks, firstly you need to know when these two are invoked. Below is the ActiveRecord callback ordering:

(-) save

(-) valid

(1) before_validation

(-) validate

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create

(-) create

(5) after_create

(6) after_save

(7) after_commit

you can see that `before_create` is called after `after_validation`, to put it in simple context, this callback is called after your ActiveRecord has met validation. This `before_create` is normally used to set some extra attributes after validation.

now move on to `after_create`, you can see this is created after the record is stored persistently onto DB. People normally use this to do things like sending notification, logging.

And for the question, when should you use it? The answer is 'you should not use it at all'. ActiveRecord callbacks are anti-pattern and seasoned Rails developer consider it code-smell, you can achieve all of that by using Service object to wrap around. Here is one simple example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_mileage_to_zero
  after_create  :send_quality_report_to_qa_team
end

can be rewritten in

# app/services/car_creation.rb

class CarCreation

  attr_reader :car

  def initialize(params = {})
    @car = Car.new(params)
    @car.mileage = 0
  end

  def create_car
    if car.save
      send_report_to_qa_team
    end 
  end

  private

  def send_report_to_qa_team
  end
end
```

If you have simple app, then callback is okay, but as your app grows, you will be scratching your head not sure what has set this or that attribute and testing will be very hard.

On second thought, I still think you should extensively use callback and experience the pain refactoring it then you'll learn to avoid it ;) goodluck

Comment: Thanks! Never seen service objects before.Though I'm not sure if the 2 options are the same. In the former if send_quality_report_to_qa_team fails, the object creation will fail, while in the latter it will succeed.  I believe that all the active recrod callback are part of the same transaction, if any of them fail, the db operations is rolled back

Answer (score 5):

The `before_create` callback can be used to set attributes on the object before it is saved to the database. For example, generating a unique identifier for a record. Putting this in an `after_create` would require another database call.

Answer (score 5):

**before_create:**

will be called before saving new object in db. When this method will return false it will prevent the creation by rolling back.

So when you need to do something like check something before saving **which is not appropriate in validations** you can use them in before_create.

For example: before creation of new `Worker` ask `Master` for permission.

```
before_create :notify_master

def notify_master
  # notify_master via ipc and 
  # if response is true then return true and create this successfully
  # else return false and rollback
end
```

Another use is as `Trung Lê` suggested you want to format some attribute before saving
like capitalizing name etc.

**after_create:**

Called after saving object in database for first time. Just when you don't want to interrupt creation and just take a note of creation or trigger something after creation this is useful.

for example: After creating new `user` with role `mod` we want to notify other mods

after_create :notify_mod, :is_mod?

```
def notify_mod
  # send notification to all other mods
end
```

**EDIT:** for below comment

Q: What's the advantage of putting `notify_mod` in `after_create` instead of `before_create`?

A: Sometimes while saving the object in database it can rollback due to database side validations or due to other issues.

Now if you have written `notify_mod` in before create then it will be processed even if the creation is not done. No doubt it will rollback but it generates overhead. so it's time consuming

If you have placed it in `after_create` then `notify_mod` will only execute if the record is created successfully. Thus decreasing the overhead if the rollback takes places.

Another reason is that it's logical that notification must be sent after user is created not before.

Comment: make sense (that's how I use it too). But what's the advantage of putting notify_mod in after_create instead of before_create? I guess it makes the call cleaner....